# Need explanation of ecef to enu algorithm

Tags: algorithm, gps, coordinates

I found some useful coordinate conversion code at https://gist.github.com/govert/1b373696c9a27ff4c72a

However, there is a bit specifically in the EcefToEnu function that I'm not clear on

```
// Converts the Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed (ECEF) coordinates (x, y, z) to 
// East-North-Up coordinates in a Local Tangent Plane that is centered at the 
// (WGS-84) Geodetic point (lat0, lon0, h0).
public static void EcefToEnu(double x, double y, double z,
                                double lat0, double lon0, double h0,
                                out double xEast, out double yNorth, out double zUp)
{
    // Convert to radians in notation consistent with the paper:
    var lambda = DegreesToRadians(lat0);
    var phi = DegreesToRadians(lon0);
    var s = Sin(lambda);
    var N = a / Sqrt(1 - e_sq * s * s);

    var sin_lambda = Sin(lambda);
    var cos_lambda = Cos(lambda);
    var cos_phi = Cos(phi);
    var sin_phi = Sin(phi);

    double x0 = (h0 + N) * cos_lambda * cos_phi;
    double y0 = (h0 + N) * cos_lambda * sin_phi;
    double z0 = (h0 + (1 - e_sq) * N) * sin_lambda;

    double xd, yd, zd;
    xd = x - x0;
    yd = y - y0;
    zd = z - z0;

    // This is the matrix multiplication
    xEast = -sin_phi * xd + cos_phi * yd;
    yNorth = -cos_phi * sin_lambda * xd - sin_lambda * sin_phi * yd + cos_lambda * zd;
    zUp = cos_lambda * cos_phi * xd + cos_lambda * sin_phi * yd + sin_lambda * zd;
}
```

I get the inputs, the first 4 conversion lines, the 4 sin and cos lines and I get the matrix multiplication - there are numerous examples with that in the algorithm.  But what I'm not clear on is the part

```
    double x0 = (h0 + N) * cos_lambda * cos_phi;
    double y0 = (h0 + N) * cos_lambda * sin_phi;
    double z0 = (h0 + (1 - e_sq) * N) * sin_lambda;

    double xd, yd, zd;
    xd = x - x0;
    yd = y - y0;
    zd = z - z0;
```

I don't recognize this section from any of the algorithms I've seen.  It appears to be some sort of offset, but aside from that, I'm unclear where the formulas came from or what exactly this code is doing.  Can someone please enlighten me as to what this bit of code is doing?  I just want to understand what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2):

They are the conversion from geodetic coordinates (lat,long,height) aka (phi,lambda,h0) to ecef cartesians (x0,y0,z0) and then the computation of the ecef vector from (x0,y0,n0) to (x,y,z).

For the first part, note that if the ellipsoid were a sphere (e==0) then the first part would be the conversion from spherical polars to cartesians